# custom sprintf in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a custom `sprintf` to format strings, with no need to pass a variable to write output to.

What I'm doing is traversing the given string with a `for` loop, finding `%` char, moving a char forward, `switch`-`case` that next char

Here is the code:

**utils.c**:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utils.h>

char *concat(char *p_format, ...) {
   char *p_concat_str = calloc(1, sizeof(char));

   va_list args;
   va_start(args, p_format);

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(p_format); ++i) {
      if (p_format[i] == '%') {
         i++;

         void *p_arg_str = va_arg(args, char *);
         /* printf("%s\n", (char *)p_arg_str); */
         p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str, (strlen(p_arg_str) + 1));
         switch (p_format[i]) {
            case 's':
               strcat(p_concat_str, (char *)p_arg_str);
               /* printf("%s\n", (char *)p_arg_str); */
               break;
         }
      }
      p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str, i + 2);
      p_concat_str[i] = p_format[i];
      p_concat_str[i + 1] = '\0';
   }

   return p_concat_str;
}
```

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utils.h>

int main() {
   char *p_world = "World";
        /* Hello World */
   char *p_str = concat("Hello %s", p_world);
   printf("Formatted str: %s | its len %lu\n", p_str, strlen(p_str));
   free(p_str);
   return 0;
}
```

But I can't realloc p_concat_str length and can't append the argument returned by va_arg to p_concat_str with strcat

This is what I got

```bash
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/prxvvy/workspace/cutils/cmake-build-debug
[2/2] Linking C executable cutils
Formatted str: Hello Ws | its len 8
```

Comment: `realloc(p_concat_str, i + 2);` Why `i+2`? That will not keep  the concatenated part of the string.

Comment: `strlen(p_arg_str)` only makes sense for `%s`, not other types. That code needs to be in `case 's':`

Comment: The statement `p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str, (strlen(p_arg_str) + 1));` does  not allocate enough memory if there's more than one argument.  You need to allocate enough space for what's already there plus what you're about to add, plus the null byte.  You need to track how much space you have allocated.

Comment: ah, I thought I could append each char that wasn't % to p_concat_str but firstly finding % and reallocating

Comment: After you execute the `if (p_format[i] == '%') { ... }` block, you "fall through" [and execute] the non-% code. You probably want: `if (p_format[i] == '%') { ... continue; }`

Comment: Just don't allocate stuff at random. Be sure about what the type you allocate memory for needs. Instead of trying to solve this in your existing program, start a new project to investigate how these things work on a basic level. Then, pick this project up when you've gotten that "aha" feeling.

Comment: Can you please clarify which of the following is your primary motivation for this: A) do your own simplified parsing; B) avoid the need to supply a buffer to `sprintf`. If the answer is actually B, as implied by your question, then I recommend using `vsnprintf` instead. That gives you industry-standard formatting and no mucking around with reallocations. Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Gqxsn6x6x). If this is actually what you want, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the size you pass to `realloc` is incorrect: instead of `p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str, (strlen(p_arg_str) + 1));` you should write:

  ```
    p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str,
                           strlen(p_concat_str) + strlen(p_arg_str) + 1);
  ```
- you always assume there is a string argument, before testing for the `s` conversion format.
- you always attempt to concatenate the character from the format string, even if you handled a conversion format.
- you reallocate `p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str, i + 2);` and copy the character at `p_concat_str[i]` for this but the destination string may be larger (or even smaller) if some `%s` conversions have been handled already.

Here is a modified using the same simplistic approach:

**utils.h:**

```
char *concat(const char *p_format, ...);
```

**utils.c:**

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utils.h"

char *concat(const char *p_format, ...) {
    char *p_concat_str = calloc(1, 1);
    if (!p_concat_str)
        return NULL;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, p_format);
    size_t dlen = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; p_format[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        if (p_format[i] == '%' && p_format[i + 1] == 's') {
            const char *p_arg_str = va_arg(args, const char *);
            i++;
            if (p_arg_str == NULL)
                p_arg_str = "(null)";
            slen = strlen(p_arg_str);
            char *newp = realloc(p_concat_str, dlen + slen + 1);
            if (newp == NULL) {
                free(p_concat_str);
                p_concat_str = NULL;
                break;
            }
            p_concat_str = newp;
            memcpy(p_concat_str + dlen, p_arg_str, slen + 1);
        } else {
            char *newp = realloc(p_concat_str, dlen + 1 + 1);
            if (newp == NULL) {
                free(p_concat_str);
                p_concat_str = NULL;
                break;
            }
            p_concat_str = newp;
            p_concat_str[dlen++] = p_format[i];
            p_concat_str[dlen] = '\0';
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
    return p_concat_str;
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utils.h"

int main() {
   char *p_world = "World";
        /* Hello World */
   char *p_str = concat("Hello %s", p_world);
   printf("Formatted str: %s | its len %zu\n", p_str, strlen(p_str));
   free(p_str);
   return 0;
}
```

You could improve the code by only reallocating the destination string when you reach a `%s` or the end of the string, concatenating a whole string fragment at a time.

If you want to handle more than just `%s`, instead of reinventing the wheel, you might use a wrapper on `vnsprintf`:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utils.h"

char *vconcat(const char *format, va_list ap) {
    char buf[256];
    va_list args;
    int ret;
    char *str;

    va_copy(args, ap);
    ret = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof buf, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (ret < 0 || (str = malloc(ret + 1)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (ret < (int)sizeof(buf)) {
        return memcpy(str, buf, ret + 1);
    } else {
        ret = vsnprintf(str, ret + 1, format, ap);
        if (ret < 0) {
            free(str);
            str = NULL;
        }
        return str;
    }
}

char *concat(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    char *str;

    va_start(args, format);
    str = vconcat(format, args);
    va_end(args);

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Why reallocating by the length of the string plus the length of the variable in va_arg? Say we've got `"%s world"` format, % is at the very beginning, at first you allocate memory for 1 element at `char *p_concat_str = calloc(1, 1);`and then for each iteration you reallocate by the length of the string (1) and plus the variable? why? if at first its 1 element allocated then it'd be reallocated by the length of the variable (in case its a string) and so on for each iteration

Comment: @prxvvy: I am not sure what you mean by *the length of the variable in va_arg`. The memory block is reallocated to `dlen + slen + 1` bytes to accommodate for the `dlen` characters already copied to it, `slen` characters copied from the string pointed to by `p_arg_str` and a null terminator.

Comment: this `p_concat_str = realloc(p_concat_str,
                         strlen(p_concat_str) + strlen(p_arg_str) + 1);`

Comment: The size passed to `realloc` is the total number of bytes: since you are going to append the string in `p_arg_str` to the end of the string already in `p_concat_str`, the total space needed is `strlen(p_concat_str) + strlen(p_arg_str) + 1`. In the modified version, I keep track of the current length of `p_concat_str` in `dlen` and compute `strlen(p_arg_str)` in `slen`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `vsnprintf()` inside your `concat()` function to detect length of output string. If you don't pass the destination buffer and its size, `vsnprintf()` will only count the length of the output string and return it.

I think this way is relatively optimal, less `malloc/realloc` will be required for the program and the code will be slightly better readable.

```
char *concat(char *p_format, ...)
{
    va_list args, tmp;
    va_start(args, p_format);

#ifdef va_copy
    va_copy(tmp, args);
#else
    memcpy(&tmp, &args, sizeof(va_list));
#endif

    int length = vsnprintf(0, 0, p_format, tmp);
    va_end(tmp);

    if (length <= 0)
    {
        va_end(args);
        return NULL
    }

    char *dst_buf = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
    if (dst_buf == NULL)
    {
        va_end(args);
        return NULL;
    }

    int bytes = vsnprintf(dst_buf, length + 1, p_format, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (bytes <= 0)
    {
        free(dst_buf);
        return NULL;
    }

    dst_buf[bytes] = '\0';
    return dst_buf;
}
```

P.S. The GNU extension of the C library contains the function `vasprintf` which can be used to achieve the same result:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

char* concat(const char *p_format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char *dst_buf = NULL;
    int length = 0;

    va_start(args, p_format);
    length = vasprintf(&dst_buf, p_format, args);
    va_end(args);

    if (length <= 0 && dst_buf)
    {
        free(dst_buf);
        return NULL;
    }

    dst_buf[length] = '\0';
    return dst_buf;
}
```